# How select text from ORACLE XE SQL command line?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How select text from ORACLE XE SQL command line  ? [image]

Comment: Your question is not clear (to me)

Comment: Type `/` on a separate line, then press Enter. This should execute your query. Best of luck.